How do I get rid of this error? Prettier: [error] No supported files were found in the directory: "views"
I keep getting the following error when I run Prettier in the cli.
[error] No supported files were found in the directory: "views".

I am running:
Node v20.16.0
On:
Windows 11

I am building an API using Express. I have included the following .prettierignore:
**/*.html
views 
node_modules

And the following .prettierrc:
{
   "tabWidth": 3,
   "useTabs": false,
   "singleQuote": true,
   "jsxSingleQuote": true
}

And the following Git BASH version:
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

Prettier is working fine, in that it's formatting my JS documents. I just want to get rid of the error at the end of the script's processing. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Is the views folder located at the same folder level as the .prettierignore? Maybe doing the ignore like this would solve your issue?
**/*.html
**/views <<< add the views like this???
node_modules

Following this docs https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore
Or you can go and add a .prettierignore inside the views folder with the following content:
file: views/.prettierignore
*

this will instruct prettier to ignore everything inside that folder you can check that at this article: https://devinschumacher.com/how-to-disable-prettier-formatting-for-individual-files-or-folders/
I prefer to use the prettier doc instruction, and set it as the first option mentioned, but if the second option solves your problem go for it!

Adding the .prettierignore file with the wildcard solved it. I had tried adding /views to the .prettierignore folder but that didn't solve it. Then I combined the idea and added /view/* to the .prettierignore file and that solved the issue without adding an additional .prettierignore file.
